# NodeJs Render SSRS Report to PDF in a browser window

Tags: node.js, reporting-services, pdf-generation, ssrs-2008

I have an NodeJS/Express app in which I would like to render SSRS report in the browser window instead of downloading it.
Here is relevant code:

```
   reporturl='http://mysqlserver/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fMyReports%2fmyreportname&rs:Format=PDF&param1=1&param2=2&param3=3'   
   window.open(reporturl, '_blank')
```

When executed reports is rendered as pdf file and immediately downloaded, however I would like to open that pdf file in a new browser window.